# How to make an expert system

Tags: c#

i am a beginer of C# and i was thinking to create a system which would add the data as the user enters it

for eg: a general store software, first time user made an entry of Tissue paper ,next time if first term is similar to "t" for tissue box automatically any tool(what u'll prefer) will pops up and show the option of tissue box to select

please reply asap

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: QuestionMarkIsMissingException was thrown

Comment: this is not an expert system!!!!!

Comment: catch (QuestionMarkIsMissingException) { question.Text.append("?") } ... *scnr*

Comment: @user485190 what you are looking for is called auto-completition, or word-completition

Comment: @Dark, I'm doing `VoteToClose(Reason.NotRealQuestion);` in catch for this exception

Comment: Do delete this question but first reply to my question atleast u get it so help me out and also what is the difference b/w expert system and this

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system ---- An expert system is some sort of large knowledge base with an intuitive interface. Auto-completion could be part of a larger expert system as it pulls from this knowledge base, but more commonly the interface is some sort of artificial intelligence simulator trying to emulate a human.

Answer (score 2):

Store previous entries in a list.  Then when the user types in a letter, search the list for entries that match.

Comment: i dont know the codes for calling data when saved in database in control (list view i guess)

Comment: user485190 I think you are in above your head. You need to start smaller it would seem and work your way up. I recommend [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Visual-2010-Step/dp/0735626707/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1309357364&sr=1-6).